# Porque no puedo obtener los datos con Axios y Vuex?

Tags: nodejs, vue.js, mongodb, axios, vuex

estoy intentando obtener datos de una API con AXIOS y VUEX (la API fue creada con Nodejs y MongoDB)
acá esta mi store

```
export default new Vuex.Store(
{state: {
productos: [],
},
mutations: {
setProductos(state, payload){
  state.productos = payload;
}
},
actions: {
getProductos({commit}){
  this.axios.get('/productos')
  .then((res) => {
    commit('setProductos', res.data)
  })
}
},
```

acá esta mi componente Productos

```
<v-simple-table>
            <template v-slot:default>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th class="text-left">
                    Nombre
                </th>
                <th class="text-left">
                    Precio Publico
                </th>
                <th class="text-left">
                    Ver datos
                </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(item) in productos" :key="item.index">
                    <td>{{ item.nombre }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <v-chip outlined color="primary" dark>${{ item.precioPublico }}</v-chip>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </template>
        </v-simple-table>

export default {
name: 'Producto',
data() {
    return {
    }
},
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['getProductos'])
},
created() {
    this.getProductos()
},
computed: {
    ...mapState(['productos'])
}
}
</script>
```

no se exactamente en que estoy fallando pero sin duda, creo que el problema esta a la hora de programar el Actions, si alguien tuvo algún problema similar y me podría ayudar se lo agradecería

y este es el error que me tira la consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema puede estar porque en el store esttás poniendo `this.axios.get(...` y axios no existe en ese ámbito. Tendrías que importar axios en el store `import axios from 'axios'` y luego usar directamente `axios.get(...`

Comment: muchísimas gracias, me sirvió la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te esta faltando importar el modulo de axios

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

intenta hacerlo de esta manera

```
export default new Vuex.Store(
    {
        state: {
            productos: [],
        },
        mutations: {
            setProductos(state, payload) {
                state.productos = payload;
            }
        },
        actions: {
            getProductos({ commit }) {
                import axios from 'axios';
                axios.get('/productos')
                    .then((res) => {
                        commit('setProductos', res.data)
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
            }
        }
    });
```

siempre maneja tus excepciones para saber en que te esta fallando

suponiendo claro que ya tengas instalado Axios, si no ejecuta
npm install -g axios

Comment: muchísimas gracias, esto me ayudo, tenia instalado Axios Vue, pero no sabia que tenia que importarlo, pensé que lo reconocía igual que el componente

Comment: Que bueno que te ayudo, podrias ayudar a marcar la respuesta como correcta? asi los demas sabran que solucion tendria